# Add new button to ribbon

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, web-part, ribbon

I want to add a new button to the ribbon called "Closed", this button will update the column to "closed" in my "Status" Column inside my list. Also all the lines that got "Closed" status the button will be not clickable anymore.

How could i add a button to the ribbon and customize my actions?

Thank you!

Comment: Any idea how could i do that ?

Comment: are you using sharepoint in classic mode?

Answer (score 0):

Add custom action by JSOM so you could add enable/disable logic for your custom action.

[Create Ribbon Custom Action Using JavaScript Object Model](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-ribbon-custom-action-using-javascript-object-model-in-sharepoint-2016-and/)

To eanble/disable custom action, check the demo in below thread.

[Enabling custom ribbon buttons dynamically based on multiple selected item values using RefreshCommandUI and JSOM](https://dannyjessee.com/blog/index.php/2014/06/enabling-custom-ribbon-buttons-dynamically-based-on-multiple-selected-item-values-using-refreshcommandui-and-jsom/)

Comment: Both of these tutorials are helpful but i want to know how can i add XML file and CustomAction.js to my SharePoint Online to test it ? @Lee_MSFT